# Password protect adobe acrobat file

Tags: adobe-reader

I found [this](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/acrobat-tips-and-tricks/protecting-your-pdf-using-a-password/) video from adobe how to protect your document. I am using latest Adobe Acrobat Reader 9. **Note I am trying to put password inside the reader itself**. If I go to

> File > properties > security

everything is simply disabled. If I go to

> help > plugins

There is a plugin for security but I can't seem to find it or install it to put that feature in. Does anyone know regarding **Adobe Acrobat Reader only**. If it can't be achieved with Reader alone, than other help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Acrobat Reader can only show you PDF files, editing is not available.
To protect a PDF file you need Adobe Acrobat Pro.
I'm not sure but it might be also available in third party tools (more likely in commercial ones).

Comment: But even security feature can't be added through a plugins?

Comment: @Dave: No, Adobe Reader is only for viewing.